# Is it okay to use Past Simple with Past Progressive for two consecutive actions?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, progressive-aspect

Is it okay to use Past Simple with Past Progressive for two consecutive actions?

For example,

"She **added** some water to the flour and **was mixing**  it until she got a lump of dough"

or should it be

"She **added** some water to the flour and **mixed** it until she got a lump of dough" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As complete sentences, the second looks better to me.

> She added some water to the flour and mixed it until she got a lump of dough.

But these are also acceptable, though with slightly different meanings:

> She added some water to the flour and was mixing it when he came into to the kitchen

or

> She had added some water to the flour and was mixing it until she got a lump of dough.